# Get the keys actionscript 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, key

Im having a little trouble with ActionScript3 when using arrays and custom keys.

This is how I defined a test-array:

```
var array:Array = new Array();
array[100] = "test1";
array[101] = "test2";
```

Now I can loop this using:

```
for each(var entry:String in array)
{
  trace(entry);
}
```

which will give me the following output:

```
test1
test2
```

but I am looking to get what key these strings belong to ([100][101])

I could always do a for (i...) loop and check for assigned data, but since this data may be have keys ranging from 0 to thousands and upwards that seems awful.

Is there a nice way to loop this array or should I just redesign to storing an object and keeping a key and value in there?

Comment: try `array.indexOf('test1');`

Comment: At the place Im traversing through the loop I don't know what is in where, so I can't do it that way im afraid.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
for ( var key:String in array ) trace("key is: " + key + " and value " + array[key]);
```

Comment: That's it. The main idea is that "for each" loops through values and "for" loops through keys.